# extracting messages and adding them to word document

Tags: python, message

PS: keep in mind i'm still a begginner so bear with me :)

i want to create a program that takes all previously sent messages (specifically on tiktok dms) and adds them to a specific word document, but the problem is that 1) i dont know how to "connect" the messaging app to the code and 2) i basically have no idea how to do the code

so basically i'm clueless, any advice? (i have tried to use the python console to create a new word document and add some text to it but that's about it

```
import docx

doc = doc.Document()

doc.add_paragraph("text")

doc.save("name")
```

help would be appreciated i'm kinda desperate :)

Comment: What messaging app are you using? Does it have any API?

Comment: i was thinking the tiktok dm's since it's easy to send messages to people without them receiving it (for trial)